# Django REST framework HyperlinkedModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on streamlining how I include different models in the API for my Djangp app.  Previously I had it set it where each model had a Viewset and a Serializer separately defined for it.  Instead I'm working on a more generic method whereby I just pass in a Model and a list of relevant fields, and will be added to the API automatically.  The problem I'm running in to currently is with defining the serializer_class:

```
from myapp import MyModel
from rest_framework.serializers import HyperlinkedModelSerializer
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

app_name = 'myapp'
fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

# Problem is here
serializer_class = HyperlinkedModelSerializer(model=MyModel, fields=fields)
viewset = ModelViewSet(queryset=queryset, serializer_class=serializer_class)

# Then to register it all with the router:
self.register(app_name + '/' +  model.__name__, viewset)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'
```

The problem seems to be that in HyperlinkedModelSerializer, 'model' and 'fields' are normally defined as Meta options so it doesn't seem to accept them when they are provided in this way.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably define a specific init with a lot of weird things or declare your class on the fly with [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```
MyMeta = type(
    'Meta',
    [],
    {"model": MyModel, "fields": fields},
)
MyHyperlinkedModelSerializer = type(
    'MyHyperlinkedModelSerializer',
    (HyperlinkedModelSerializer,),
    {'Meta': MyMeta},
)
viewset = ModelViewSet(
    queryset=queryset,
    serializer_class= MyHyperlinkedModelSerializer,
)
```

Comment: Line 3:

    NameError: name 'Meta' is not defined

Comment: wooops, forgot the Meta class doesn't inherit from anything. Post updated.

Comment: Hm, the problem I get now is when I try to register it:

self.register(app_name + '/' +  model.__name__, viewset)

There's a lot of errors being displayed, but I think it comes down to:

AttributeError: This method is available only on the class, not on instances.